# Consuming wcf web service using java client with digest authentication

Tags: java, web-services, wcf

Consuming wcf web service using java client with digest authentication like example,
I can not identify the equivalent of java to ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName

.Net Example

```
Catalogo.CatalogoWSClient proxy = new Catalogo.CatalogoWSClient();

string user = "usuario";
string pass = "senha";

proxy.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = user;
proxy.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = pass;
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = user;
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = pass;
```

Comment: Which Java library are you using?

Comment: Jaxws ((BindingProvider) client).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, USER);
        ((BindingProvider) client).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, PASSWD);

Comment: If your using the standard JDK, I'm not sure if it supports digest authentication yet.  You may need to switch the library to something like Apache CXF